# Compare WOFF files

Tags: woff, fontforge

I wonder if it's possible (in windows or ubuntu) to compare woff font files. Is there a way to find out if two files contain the samy glyphs etc.?
I take a `.ttf` file and compress it to `.woff` using `fontforge` on Ubuntu. A ttf file with a size of 220 kb is shrunk to 69 kb.

```
fontforge -lang=ff -c '
Open("OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
Generate("OpenSans-Bold.woff");
Quit(0);'
```

I take the tool that was available on jkew's people.mozilla page and the file is shrunk to 113 kb.

```
sfnt2woff.exe OpenSans-Bold.ttf
```

What's the difference between the 2 files? Only the compression or also the content?

Answer (score 0):

Open both font files in FontForge and the select the Element > Compare Fonts menu item. If you have two fonts open, there is only one choice for the comparison…

The result will tell you any missing glyphs and other differences.